# Как транслировать видео игры на YouTube сделанной в Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, youtube, streaming, broadcasting

Делаю игру на Андройд и iOs в Unity, в ней должна быть возможность транслировать игру на YouTube. Каким путем это можно реализовать?

Comment: Это точно надо реализовывать в игре? Я всегда думал, что это просто доп ПО ставят на устройство для трансляции

Comment: Ну это желание заказчика, хочется узнать реально ли это вообще сделать...